# children items when clicked change the parent color

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I have a menu with multiple `ul` items. What i want is change the color of top menu text to red.

However this only works when i click in the first item, not in the children items.

For example, i want to click in `hydrotherapy` and change to red the word `Services`. The parent. Any idea?

```
$("nav.menu>ul>li").children().click(function() {
    alert("asd");
    var item1 = $(this),
        primeira_ul = item1.closest('.menu>ul#nav>li>a.t2');

    item1.addClass('font_red');
    return false;
});
```

***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dPeLZ/1/)***

Comment: Is [this what you wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dPeLZ/3/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for the first child of `$(this)` that is an `a` tag.  Note that `$(this)` refers not to the event source, but the **`$("nav.menu>ul>li")`** element which is already your top level `li`.

You probably also want to unset the siblings.

```
$("nav.menu>ul>li").on("click", function() {
    var item1 = $(this),
        primeira_ul = item1.closest('.menu>ul#nav>li>a.t2');

    $(this).siblings().find("> a").removeClass('font_red');
    $(this).find("> a").first().addClass('font_red');
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPeLZ/5/)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to look for the closest `ul.first_level` in the first round, then use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get the link itself (not making major modifications in your code, just changing the parts with the problem):

```
$("nav.menu>ul>li").children().click(function() {
    var item1 = $(this);
    var theLink = item1.closest('.first_level').siblings('.t2');

    theLink.addClass('font_red');
    return false;
});​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dPeLZ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$("nav.menu>ul>li").children().click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('#nav>li:has(.t2)').find('>a').addClass('font_red');
});​
```